# Split categories list with custom field into two columns (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to get a list of categories into two columns. Each category has a custom field ("color") created with ACF. So far so good, i can get the list in a single column with this code:

```
<?php
          $args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0');
          $categories = get_categories($args);
          if($categories){
            echo '<div class="col"><ul class="cat-list">';
            foreach($categories as $category) {
              $color = get_field('color', 'category_'.$category->term_id);
              echo '<li style="background-color:'.$color.'">';
              echo '<a href="';
              echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) );
              echo '">';
              echo $category->name;
              echo '</a>';
              echo '</li>';
            } 
            echo '</ul></div>';
          }    
          ?>
```

Now i’m trying to get the list using wp_list_categories (tip: https://wpsquare.com/display-wordpress-categories-two-columns/). This works as a solution for the two columns issue, but with this method i can’t retrieve the value from the category custom field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$categories` is an array. One of the great things you can do with an array is... look how many items you have in them, and iterate over them using a simple for-loop.

```
<?php
  $args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0');
  $categories = get_categories($args);
  if(!empty($categories)) {
    $last_category_nr = count($categories) - 1;
    $last_in_first_column = ceil($last_category_nr / 2);
?>
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="cat-list">
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $last_in_first_column; $i++) { 
          $category = $categories[$i];
          $color = get_field('color', $category);
          $link = esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) );
          $name = $category->name;
        ?>
        <li style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
          <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <?php echo $name; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="cat-list">
        <?php
        for ($i = $last_in_first_column + 1; $i <= $last_category_nr; $i++) { 
          $category = $categories[$i];
          $color = get_field('color', $category);
          $link = esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) );
          $name = $category->name;
        ?>
        <li style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
          <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
            <?php echo $name; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  }    
?>
```